# Input Queue not responding TensorFlow program hanging

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am currently trying to train a neural network. I have an array of file names and their corresponding labels. However I am having issues when trying to train the network.

```
image_list, label_list = readImageLables()

images = ops.convert_to_tensor(image_list, dtype=dtypes.string)
labels = ops.convert_to_tensor(label_list, dtype=dtypes.int32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init_op)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
    for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
        epoch_loss = 0
        for _ in range(int(7685/batch_size)):
            print(labels.eval())
            filename_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([images,labels], num_epochs=10, shuffle=True)
            image,label = read_images_from_disk(filename_queue)
            print(image.eval())
            epoch_x, epoch_y = tf.train.batch([image, label], batch_size=batch_size)
            print("wait what")
            #imgs, lbls = epoch_x.eval(), epoch_y.eval()
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x.eval(), y: epoch_y.eval()})
            epoch_loss += c

        print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of',hm_epochs,'loss:',epoch_loss)
```

At the line in which I am trying to print the image data, the program hangs. Even when this line is removed, the program is hanging on the last sess.run call in which I am feeding this data. I have initialized queue runners, coordinators, etc. However, I have a feeling that the filename_queue is having an issue. Is there anything I am missing in the tf.train.slice_input_producer line? Also is the program hanging or is it just taking a while to load. How much time would it usually take to load an epoch with a batch size of 100 and images of 80 by 70?

Comment: Do you see the program taking any resources on `top` or `nvidia-smi`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an issue I opened. While feeding data the input queue runners was hanging. This is because you have to start it.

From the [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5396), we have:

> Quoting: *RudrakshTuwani*
>   For anyone else struggling with this, please read the documentation as
>   mentioned by girving. For the lazy ones:
>
> ```
> init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
> sess.run(init)
> threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners()
> print(sess.run(name_of_output_tensor))
> ```

As well as:

> From: *girving*
>   You probably need to start queue runners. Please see the documentation
>   at https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/threading_and_queues/index.html

Hope it helps!
`pltrdy`

---

Note that in my case I got confused because the [original code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py#L352) was using:

```
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir=FLAGS.save_path)
    with sv.managed_session() as session:
```

instead of my (and your):

```
with tf.Session() as session:
```

The first one actually implicitely starts queue runners.